# getElement 1 and do1, getElement 2 and do2, getElement 3 and do3

Tags: javascript

I have this code for smooth scrolling, it works great but only for one "clickme" id, how could i use this code for multiple tabs whit i++

```
<div class="navbar">
  <button type="button" id="clickme1">Scroll to red section!</button>
  <button type="button" id="clickme2">Scroll to blue section!</button>
</div>

<div class="second" id="second">Hello</div>
<div class="tab1" id="tab1">The start of the red section!</div>
<div class="tab2" id="tab2">The start of the blue section!</div>
```

and here is the pure javascript that i want to use, please do not recommend me jQuery and anchor navigation.

```
document.getElementById('clickme1').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();

    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('tab1'));
});
```

*******or more simplified, how can i make this code shorter:*******

```
document.getElementById('clickme1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();

    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('tab1'));
});

document.getElementById('clickme2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();

    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('tab2'));
});
```

here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9974tyyb/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
// Get buttons
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    // Iterate over buttons and add handler
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}

// Handler function
function clickHandler(){
    var counter = this.id.substring(7); // Substring id to get counter
    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();
   smoothScroll(document.getElementById('tab'+counter));
}
```

**Note** : As you can have some other buttons on your page and do not want to add this handler to them, so, in place of tag name selector, I will suggest you to add a specific class to the button elements and then use class selector to get elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using proper anchor links with progressive enhancement for smooth scrolling.  This would involve either changing the buttons to `<a>` tags or just wrapping them:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#tab1"><button type="button">Scroll to red section!</button></a>
  <a href="#tab2"><button type="button">Scroll to blue section!</button></a>
</div>
```

You can then use *event delegation* to trap clicks on any anchor link at the document level:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var tgt = evt.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === 'A' && tgt.getAttribute('href')[0] === '#') {
        smoothScroll(document.getElementById(tgt.hash.slice(1)));
    }
});
```

There are numerous benefits to this approach, including:

- Ability to hotlink to a section by copy/pasting the URL
- Graceful degrading when JavaScript is not present.